# Can anyone help me with proving why every eigenvalue is real number?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a transformation $T$ such that $T(f)=g$, where $g= tf'(t)$

And, I have to prove why every real $\lambda$ is eigenvalue for $T $

First of all ,

I set   $λf(t)=t f'(t)$

and I found out that  $f(t)=Ct^λ$ , where $C$ is nonzero number.

It seems so obvious, by just looking at $f(t)$, that $\lambda$ is every real number.

But when It comes to actual proof of why $\lambda$ is every real, I am stuck...

Comment: What is the space your operator $T$ is acting on?

Comment: V is the linear space of all real functions differentiable on (0,1)

Comment: I tried to separate the cases, where  λ is positive, negative and zero and showed that  for any case, it satisfies  λf(t)=tf'(t)

Answer (score 4):

You have most of the right ideas, but you've scrambled them around so that it no longer looks like you answered the question.

We have a linear transformation $T$ over differentiable functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ defined by
$$
T[f(t)] = tf'(t)
$$
We say that a value $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ is an *eigenvalue* of $T$ if there exists a non-zero vector (i.e. function) $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $T[f(t)] = \lambda \,f(t)$.  That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if there exists a non-zero solution to the equation
$$
tf'(t) = \lambda f(t) \implies\\
\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} = \frac{\lambda}{t}
$$
We can solve this by integrating both sides to find the solution
$$
\log(f(t)) = \lambda \log(t) + C \implies\\
f(t) = C t^\lambda
$$
So, for a value $\lambda$, the function $f(t) = t^\lambda$ is an *eigenvector* associated with $\lambda$, making $\lambda$ an *eigenvalue* of $T$.

Note that the statement "every real number is an eigenvalue" (which looks like the statement you need to answer) is not the same as the statement "every eigenvalue is real".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how does that prove that  λ is every real number?

Comment: The equation $t\,f'(t) = \lambda f(t)$ has a non-zero solution for every real $\lambda$.  So, every real $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh,, I see the difference and thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I love you

Comment: Glad to help :)